# I'm having issues trying to set up user auth with express-session/passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, express-session

So i'm creating a mock e-commerse app where a user can register/sign in. I have an endpoint in my backend that fetches a user's profile, and in postman everything works correctly, but in my frontend logic i get 'User is not authenticated error'.

I have been trying to solve this but im just runing laps around the problem i feel like...
This is my front end api fetch code:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/user/profile", {
          credentials: "include",
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", err);
      }
    };
```

This is my endpoint code, the session id log correctly returns the session id, but the auth status is always false when fetching through my frontend, but on postman it runs perfectly...

```
profile: (req, res) => {
    try {
      console.log("Received request to /user/profile");
      console.log("Authentication status:", req.isAuthenticated());
      console.log("Session ID:", req.sessionID);

      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        const userData = { ...req.user };
        delete userData.password;
        res.json(userData);
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ message: "Not authenticated" });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
```

This is my server config:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", // Replace with the URL of your React app
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const initializePassport = require("./passport-config");
initializePassport(passport);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "b9c558dee606c2f9d035cc853a9b88f143c230ab1fbd4bfe4c76996ce1352f03",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Move the logging middleware here
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Request to", req.originalUrl);
  console.log("Session ID:", req.sessionID);
  console.log("Authentication status:", req.isAuthenticated());
  next();
});

app.use("/products", productsRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

and this is my passport config:

```
function initialize(passport) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
      const userCheck = await pool.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = $1",
        [email]
      );

      if (userCheck.rows.length === 0) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "No user with that email found." });
      }

      const user = userCheck.rows[0];
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password." });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return done(error);
    }
  };

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, authenticateUser));

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));

  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
      const userById = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1", [
        id,
      ]);
      done(null, userById.rows[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      done(error, null);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

First time posting on here so sorry if i overshared/undershared code... still learning! Any help would be greatly appreciated <3

session is being saved to cookies btw, and it is being sent in the request headers.